# Pink icons and titlebars in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, icons, colors

after the last update I have a serious problem - all icons (both within menus and programs) and titlebars have changed to a bright shade of pink. I have enclosed a screenshot.
I've found someone with [apparently the same issue on Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221169). The solution is to downgrade llvm-libs, however I can't find such a package in Xubuntu. What am I supposed to do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem thanks to ToZ from the XFCE forums. Here is the thread:
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=44372

Comment: You should summarize the issue (xorg-edgers) and the steps for the workaround here, along with the link to the bug report. :)